# Typescript 0.9.1 no option to keep comments set to off

Tags: typescript

I've just upgraded to 0.9.1 has anyone found that (besides having to find-replace : bool to : boolean) comments are copied over into generated javascript?

I want to have this suppressed but cannot find the option to turn it off in the web essentials options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The flag is now called `--removeComments` in the command-line compiler.

If at all possible, stop using the Web Essentials TypeScript features. These have been extremely problematic in the past (e.g. WE spawning one copy of tsc.exe per .ts file in your solution) and are being removed in future versions of Web Essentials. You can use the TypeScript .targets file and MSBuild task instead now.

Comment: Off-topic question: Without WE, can TypeScript automatically compile with save?

Comment: Yes; you need to have the appropriate project setup (imports the TypeScript Targets file, it's the default in the HTML App Template) and the compile-on-save options checked in Tools\Options\Text Editor\TypeScript\Project\

Comment: Not sure how to import the HTML App Template...  but compile-on-save in Tools-Options-Text Editor-TypeScript-Project is checked and WE compile-on-save unchecked, but it doesn't compile when saved.

Comment: My project was created via HTML App Template and I looked at it and it has ``<Import Project="$(VSToolsPath)\TypeScript\Microsoft.TypeScript.targets" />`` at the end.